# R extract items from string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract all words containing two adjacent vowels in this given string.

```
x <- "The team sat next to each other all year and still failed."
```

The results would be `"team", "each", "year", "failed"`

So far I have tried using `[aeiou][aeiou]` to do this with `regmatches` but it only gives me part of the word.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place `\w*` before and after the character class to match "zero or more" word characters.

```
x <- "The team sat next to each other all year and still failed."
regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\w*[aeiou]{2}\\w*', x))[[1]]
# [1] "team"   "each"   "year"   "failed"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
words <-unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
words[grepl("[aeiou]{2}", words)]
#[1] "team"    "each"    "year"    "failed."
```

If you wanted to clean up the punctuatin it could be:

```
> words <-unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:punct:] ]"))
> words[grepl("[aeiou]{2}", words)]
```

Comment: you could split using `\\W` so as to drop the final punctuation.

Comment: Thanks; my vote was for hwnd's offering. I admire the answers using `regmatches(.,gregexpr(.))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\w*[aeiou][aeiou]\w*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hJ3zB0/5

Answer (score 1):

The same with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
xx <- str_split(x, " ")[[1]]
xx[str_detect(xx, "[aeiou]{2}")]
## [1] "team"    "each"    "year"    "failed."
```

### Edit

As highlighted by @akrun it is possible to simplify this to

```
str_extract_all(x, "\\w*[aeiou]{2}\\w*")[[1]]
## [1] "team"   "each"   "year"   "failed"
```